# Vector elements to a string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to turn a `vector<int>` into a string, with a `'['` at the beginning, and a `','` between each element of the vector, and a `']'` at the end. But my output is `[,,,,]` (wanted output `[6,4,3,2,1]`).

Can you explain to me what i'm doing wrong?

Here's what I tried:

```cpp
int main() {

   std::vector<int> elements = {1,2,3,4,6};   
   std::string outputString = "[";

      
    for(int i = elements.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i > 0) {

            outputString.push_back(elements.at(i));
            outputString.push_back(',');
        }
        else {
            outputString.push_back(elements.at(i));
        }
    }
    outputString.push_back(']');
    std::cout << std::endl << outputString << std::endl;    
}
```

Comment: What do you think `outputString.push_back(elements.at(i));` does? Do you understand the difference between `1` and `'1'`?

Comment: A better approach would be to create a function that takes begin and end iterators along with a separator, and return the string.  Then you are not tied to just using vectors.

Comment: I would use a `std::ostringstream` for this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string::push_back` adds a single `char` to the string and you tripped over the implicit conversion of `int` to `char`. The low values correspond to non-printable characters, thats why you don't see them in the output.

You can use `operator+=` and `std::to_string`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

   std::vector<int> elements = {1,2,3,4,6};   
   std::string outputString = "[";

      
    for(int i = elements.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i > 0) {

            outputString += std::to_string(elements.at(i));
            outputString.push_back(',');
        }
        else {
            outputString += std::to_string(elements.at(i));
        }
    }
    outputString.push_back(']');
    std::cout << std::endl << outputString << std::endl;    
}
```

PS: I didn't even know that `std::string::push_back` exists. You can also use `operator+=` to add a single character to the string.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the integers as-is to the string, implicitly converting them to single characters. Most characters with values below 32 are non-printable. You need to convert the integers to strings, such as with `std::to_string()`.

```cpp
outputString += std::to_string(elements[i]);
```

Another way to implement this is to use `std::ostringstream` instead, let `operator<<` handle the conversion for you, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string vector_to_string_in_reverse(const std::vector<int> &elements)
{
    std::ostringstream outputStream;
    outputStream << '[';
    if (!elements.empty()) {
        auto it = elements.crbegin(), end = elements.crend();
        outputStream << *it++;
        while (it != end) {
            outputStream << ',' << *it++;
        }
    }
    outputStream << ']';
    return outputStream.str();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> elements = {1,2,3,4,6};
    std::cout << std::endl << vector_to_string_in_reverse(elements) << std::endl;
}
```